# Installing System.Numerics.Vectors via NuGet

Tags: c#, nuget

when I try installing System.Numerics.Vectors using NuGet console I getting this:

```
Package Manager Console Host Version 3.3.0.167

Type 'get-help NuGet' to see all available NuGet commands.

PM> Install-Package System.Numerics.Vectors -Version 4.1.0
Attempting to gather dependencies information for package 'System.Numerics.Vectors.4.1.0' with respect to project 'MyVeryNiceProject', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'System.Numerics.Vectors.4.1.0' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving actions to install package 'System.Numerics.Vectors.4.1.0'
Resolved actions to install package 'System.Numerics.Vectors.4.1.0'
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'System.Numerics.Vectors.4.1.0 : ' does not exist in project 'MyVeryNiceProject'
Package 'System.Numerics.Vectors.4.1.0 : ' does not exist in folder 'C:\Users\V01D\Desktop\MyVeryNiceProject\src\MyVeryNiceProject\packages'
Install-Package : Could not install package 'System.Numerics.Vectors 4.1.0'. You are trying to install this package into 
a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content 
files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package System.Numerics.Vectors -Version 4.1.0
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageComm 
   and

PM>
```

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Are you running .NET Core 5.0?

Comment: `Debug.WriteLine(".NET Core version: "+typeof(void).Assembly.ImageRuntimeVersion);`

Outputed:
_.NET Core version: v4.0.30319_

Comment: Well, there you go. That package is targeted at .NET 5.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a look at the contents of `System.Numerics.Vectors`, you'll see the frameworks that it supports.

[image: System.Numeric.Vectors\lib directory structure]

I'm not entirely sure what `dotnet` is - it appears to be a new moniker for Portable Class Libraries - but the rest definitely don't apply to your .NET Framework 4.0 project.

Considering there's support for `net46`, updating your project to target .NET Framework 4.6 or higher should do the trick.

Comment: Updated project to version 4.6 and it worked, thanks a lot!

Comment: mine is .NET Framework 4.6.1. It doesn't work... :(